# Inserting a space 2 places after a decimal in a string

Tags: php, string

In PHP, I am importing some text files containing tables of float values that are space delimited. All values contain two decimal places. A typical line would look like this:

```
1.45 22.87 99.12 19.55
```

However, some lines, if the number before the decimal is 3 digits long, the original file sometimes does not include a space. So what should be:

```
1.45 122.87 99.12 19.55
```

comes in as:

```
1.45122.87 99.12 19.55
```

What I assume I need to do is search the string for decimals, then look 2 spaces after that, and if there is not a space there I need to add one.  I just cannot for the life of me figure out the most direct way to do so.

Comment: Do you mean that it's neither delimited nor fixed width?

Comment: There are ALWAYS 2 digits afer the "."?

Comment: It's space delimited, but not always, and there are ALWAYS 2 digits after the decimal.

Comment: @user686198 Then we can do it with regular expression, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use regex:

```
    $pattern = "/(-)?\d{1,}\.\d{2}/";
    preg_match_all($pattern, "1.45122.87 99.12 19.55", $matches);
    print_r($matches);
```

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/dit0x)

Comment: Changed the pattern to "/(-)?\d{1,}\.\d{2}/" to account for negative values and this works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

This is a fixed-column-width file.  I would parse these by `substr()`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

```
for ($x=0; $x<strlen($line); $x+=4) {
    $parts[] = trim(substr($line, $x, 4));
}
```

This will get you an array in `$parts` of all the fields.  This is untested, but should work.

Comment: $x is not being incremented in your for loop

Answer (score 0):

```
$line = '1.45122.87 99.12 19.55';
preg_match_all('~([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{2})~', $line, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);

/*
  Result:

  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "1.45"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "122.87"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "99.12"
    [3]=>
    string(5) "19.55"
  }

*/
```

Answer (score 0):

This does what you want. Probably not the most efficient way to do it though.

```
<?php
    $line = "1.45122.87 99.12 19.55";

    $length = strlen($line);
    $result = '';
    $i=0;
    while ($i<$length)
    {
        if ($line[$i] == '.')
        {
            $result .= $line[$i];
            $result .= $line[$i+1];
            $result .= $line[$i+2];
            $result .= ' ';
            $i += 3;
        }
        else if ($line[$i] == ' ')
        {
            $i++;
        }
        else
        {
            $result .= $line[$i];
            $i++;
        }
    }

    echo $result;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use preg_split() to create an array of the line using regex

```
$lineArray = preg_split("/(\d+(\.\d{1,2})?)/", $lineOfNumbers);
```

This would find all instances of ####.## and not worry about the spaces

Answer (score -2):

I would do something like this, say the line of decimals is in a variable called $line:

```
$parts = explode(' ', $line);
```

Now you have an array of decimals values, so

```
$parts[0] = "1.45"
(float)$parts[0] = 1.45
$parts[1] = "122.87"
(float)$parts[1] = 122.87
// etc...
```

Comment: Not all the numbers contain spaces between them.

Comment: What I would get would be $parts[0] = 1.45122.87 What I'm trying to do is split that string INTO 1.45 1.22, not from it.

Comment: Why can't you just back up and reprocess the original file?